# Why Excel files(.xls) opened in Word under IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, phpexcel

I had A PHP File(Using PHPExcel) to deal with export Excel files.

While I using **IE8** to download a xxx.xls file, it prompt me to open it or save in somewhere. If I click open, it is just **opened in Word with mess code**. But If I click save and double click to open it, it is opened in Excel correctly, and **what I want** is that when I click open, it is just opened in Excel.

Is there any way to solve this problem in my code.

PHP code about Output information.

```
$file_name = 'export_data.xls';
$file_name = iconv('utf-8', 'gbk', $filename);
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header('Content-Disposition:inline;filename="' . $file_name . '"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Waiting for your help, THX
P.S: Browser like Chrome or FireFox, even IE9/10 worked fine.

Comment: You open an **Excel** in **Word**. Messy is a must, right?

Comment: Given that only one Content-Type header will be sent to the browser, and you're trying to send three, (none of which is correct) then is it any wonder that it gets confused.... look at the headers sent in `01simple-download-xls.php` in the `/Examples`